# Javascript newline not working when sending to outlook

Tags: javascript

I have this little problem.
I have this javascript in my html page:

```
function myfunction(form)
            {
                var name = document.details.txtName.value + "\n";
                var street = document.details.txtStreet.value + "\n";
                var city = document.details.txtCity.value + "\n";
                var stateProvince = document.details.txtStateProvince.value + "\n";
                var postalCode = document.details.txtPostalCode.value + "\n";
                var country = document.details.txtCountry.value + "\n";
                var homeTel = document.details.txtHomeTel.value + "\n";
                var workTel = document.details.txtWorkTel.value + "\n";
                var fax = document.details.txtFax.value + "\n";
                var mobile = document.details.txtMobile.value + "\n";
                var email = document.details.txtEmail.value + "\n";
                var enquiry = document.details.txtEnquiry.value + "\n";

                var message = (name +
                               street + 
                               city + 
                               stateProvince + 
                               postalCode + 
                               country + 
                               homeTel + 
                               workTel + 
                               fax + 
                               mobile + 
                               email +
                               enquiry);
                alert(message);
                location='mailto:somecrazyassemail@gmail.com?subject=Message From Redec Website&body=' + message;
                return false; //So that the page can stay at its current location.
```

In the messagebox that pops up, it displays the strings underneath each other, which I want.

but when this opens outlook it is all in one long string. how can I fix this?
                }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mailto is particular attribute. You have to encode the string using `escape` function.

But for the new lines, you can use **%0D%0A**.
See [this site](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/001023.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting the text as HTML, so new line characters `'\n'` are simply parsed as `'n'`. To insert a line break, using the corresponding HTML element `<br>`.

For example:

```
var name = document.details.txtName.value + "<br>";
//                                           ^^^^
```

Comment: Its still throwing it all as one string. Now even displaying the <br>

Comment: @Bebbie7 Oops, hold on a sec!

Comment: @Bebbie7 Try using the line feed character `&#10;`. See what happens.

Comment: @Bebbie7 Maybe JoDev's answer will help if this doesn't.

Comment: hehe that takes away the rest of the string in outlook hehe. but thanks! this will come on handy later on.